# How can I improve text recognition performance in Tesseract.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, tesseract

I am trying to recognize the number in the picture below,
but tesseract recognized as 8637.

How can I increase the accuracy?

[0632 Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQje5.png)

```
let img = 'public/captchaImg.png';

    await worker.load();
    await worker.loadLanguage('eng');
    await worker.initialize('eng');
    await worker.setParameters({
      tessedit_char_whitelist: '0123456789',
    });

    const {
      data: { text },
    } = await worker.recognize(img);

    console.log(text);

    await worker.terminate();
```

The result: 8637

Comment: Hi, please don't post your code as a picture. Rather include it as text in your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.